# Save mp4 with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Why No video saved?

```
    self.writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter("test1.mp4", cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), fps, frame_size, is_color )

    self.writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter("tsest3.mp4",cv.CV_FOURCC(*'H264'), fps, (320, 240), is_color )
    self.writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter("test4.mpg", cv.CV_FOURCC('P', 'I', 'M', '1'), fps, (320, 240), is_color )
```

I used WriteFrame too  but still no file created or the size is 0kb.

Comment: you should first threshold your image so that anything but white is blacked out. then you can remove noise (and small white object) with opening. try optical flow on the resulting image.

Comment: I would suggest simpler background subtraction for this task, instead of optical flow. See for example this excellent [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/05/25/basic-motion-detection-and-tracking-with-python-and-opencv/)

Comment: @Azad you  mean this ? https://github.com/dereks/motion_tracking

Comment: @EladJoseph I saw that but some how it will alwayz find some thing to track no matter how I change params

Answer (score 2):

According to the OpenCV [2.4.11.0 documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/highgui/video-write/video-write.html#the-structure-of-a-video)-

> However, OpenCV is mainly a computer vision library, not a video stream, codec and write one. Therefore, the developers tried to keep this part as simple as possible. Due to this OpenCV for video containers supports only the avi extension, its first version. A direct limitation of this is that you cannot save a video file larger than 2 GB.

**Workaround-**

> As an alternative, create the video track with OpenCV and expand it with sound tracks or convert it to other formats by using video manipulation programs such as VirtualDub or AviSynth.

Do read the complete section describing the structure of video files. Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/29746666/3681882