# How to sync audio and video using python

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, python-imaging-library, pyaudio

I am making a screen recorder which captures the screen and simultaneously also records the audio from microphone(input) with the help of a python script.

I am using Pillow and opencv library to record screen and using pyaudio library to record audio.

I have created a Gui using tkinter for this screen recorder(shown in image below).

So to start screen and audio recording i used buttons to start and stop different functions of scripts.

Now the problem is that duration of video file(screen recording) and the audio file(using pyaudio) is different.

ex. if user click on screen rec button and after 20-50 sec later click on voice rec button or vice-verse.

The time duration of both the file is different and can't be merge the audio and video file properly.

How can I overcome this situation?

[image: gui]

Comment: Use only **one** `Button` to. record both.

Comment: @stovfl but it is creating two seperate audio and video file. i want one video file with audio merge in it.

Comment: Relevant [video manipulation programs such as VirtualDub](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33311022/7414759)